# Why does unit testing an image field using SimpleUploadedFile create multiple images?

Tags: python, django, unit-testing

This is the tests.py

```
class ArticleModelTestCase(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.article = Article.objects.create(
            title = 'Title test.',
            content = 'Content test.',
            date_posted = timezone.localtime(),
            image = SimpleUploadedFile(
                name = 'test_image.jpg',
                content = b'',
                content_type = 'image/jpeg'
            )
        )

    def test_title(self):
        self.assertEqual(self.article.title, 'Title test.')

    def test_content(self):
        self.assertEqual(self.article.content, 'Content test.')

    def test_image_field(self):
        self.assertEqual(self.article.image.name, 'test_image.jpg')
```

and I got this error

```
> Creating test database for alias 'default'... System check identified
> no issues (0 silenced). .F.
> ====================================================================== FAIL: test_image_field (articles.tests.ArticleModelTestCase)
> ---------------------------------------------------------------------- Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/home/xxx/projects/xxxx/backend/articles/tests.py",
> line 27, in test_image_field
>     self.assertEqual(self.article.image.name, 'test_image.jpg') AssertionError: 'article_images/test_image_7U9qlax.jpg' !=
> 'test_image.jpg'
> - article_images/test_image_7U9qlax.jpg
> + test_image.jpg
> 
> 
> ---------------------------------------------------------------------- Ran 3 tests in 0.004s
> 
> FAILED (failures=1) Destroying test database for alias 'default'...
```

What happens is that the `SimpleUploadedFile` not only created a 'test_image.jpg' but it created 3 files of:

1. test_image.jpg
2. test_image_CWK5SDf.jpg
3. test_image_7U9qlax

Every time I ran the test, it will always create 3 image files with random words and numbers as the suffix after 'test_image'.

What it should do is to just create 1 image file named 'test_image'.

Why does this happen and how to fix this?

Comment: Are you removing all prior uploaded images before running the test, to make sure the filenames don't collide?

Comment: Yes, I have. It still creating 3 images file every time I ran the test

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, because there are 3 tests, `def setUp` got called 3 times, which is the reason why `SimpleUploadedFile` kept creating 3 images.

This is my new code now and it works

```
class ArticleModelTestCase(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.article = Article.objects.create(
            title='Title test.',
            content='Content test.',
            date_posted=timezone.localtime(),
            image=None
        )

    def tearDown(self):
        if self.article.image:
            os.remove(self.article.image.path)

    def test_title(self):
        self.assertEqual(self.article.title, 'Title test.')


    def test_content(self):
        self.assertEqual(self.article.content, 'Content test.')

    def test_image_field(self):
        test_image = SimpleUploadedFile(
            name='test_image.jpg',
            content=b'',
            content_type='image/jpeg'
        )
        self.article.image = test_image
        self.article.save()
        self.assertEqual(self.article.image.name, 'article_images/test_image.jpg')
```

Comment: "edit" should be applied to your original post. Please don't submit updates to the question as an answer.

Comment: @IvanStarostin It looks like OP found the solution to their own problem, and this is the working code (with `SimpleUploadedFile`) moved from `def setUp` to the test itself). I just removed the "-----EDIT-----" line because it's misleading. This is not a forum/thread format.

Comment: @IvanStarostin Sorry, this answer actually was an edit to the post. But then I saw the "Answer your own question" or something at the bottom so I cut it out then paste it as an answer. Apparently, I forgot to delete the "EDIT" part